# Json array transformation using jolt

Tags: jolt

i want to transform a JSON array,

JSON:

```
{
    "data1": {
        "data2": [
            {
                "element1": "value1",
                "entity": [
                    "array0",
                    {
                        "element2": [
                            "abc",
                            "pqr",
                            "xyz"

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

desired output:

```
"data2" : {
                    "element1":"value1",
                    "entity" : "array0",
                    "element2":[abc,pqr,xyz]
            }
```

Please find find way to transform this JSON
i have tried with different approach to access the element1 . its not working

Answer (score 0):

Spec

`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data1": {
        "data2": {
          "*": { // data2 array index
            "element1": "data2[&1].element1",
            "entity": {
              // index input entity array explicilty with "0" and "1"
              "0": "data2[&2].entity",
              "1": {
                "element2": "data2[&3].element2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`